# About writing "I can't help saying...."

Tags: meaning

I wrote in one place "I can't help to say- what a great... !". I intended to say that I can't stop myself to say or think otherwise. In my native language it had to be a double negation and I wanted this. Did I write this correctly? How should this be written correctly ?

Comment: We certainly *can* use double negation, in forms like [*You can't not say anything, I can't not speak*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22can%27t+not+say+anything%22), but they'd often require heavy stress (on ***not***, or perhaps ***say***) to alert the audience to the fact that you're using a relatively complex and unusual construction (as opposed to the more direct ***You must say something, I must speak***).

Answer (score 4):

One way to correct this sentence would be to rephrase it using a 'but': "I can't help **but** say -what a great... !" In a way, this uses the double negation you intended and also stresses how much you appreciate whatever it is you are appreciating here :)

Comment: Thank you! I must understand  that the correct sentence is without the word  ,,to''.